# Nullable object must have a value while using datepicker control with dropdown control

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have screen on which i pulling up results from stored procedure, now i added a dropdown list on top of it which say "Today" and that pulls up the entries created today, "week", "month", "year" and everything is working fine, now i want to add a custom option to it and when user select that, 2 datepickers will come up

now everything except "custom" is working fine, but when i click custom option it gives me following error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.`

```
DataTable dtbl = BIZ.ReportsBIZAdmin.ReportsCoursesFilter(dtStart, dtEnd.Value);
```

Line 218

please help me if its a post back problem and how to solve it

### P.S.

```
string strVal = hdnOption.Value;
IFormatProvider provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", true);
DateTime dtStart = new DateTime();
DateTime? dtEnd = null;
string strCourses = ddlCourses.SelectedValue;

//DateTime.Parse(txtdtStart.Text.ToString().Trim(), provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);


if (strVal == "today")
{
    //dtStart = Convert.ToInt32(ddlFilter.SelectedValue)
    dtStart = DateTime.Today;
    dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
}
if (strVal == "weekly")
{

    dtStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).Date;
    dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
    FillGridFilter(dtStart, dtEnd);
}
if (strVal == "byweekly")
{
    dtStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15).Date;
    dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
    FillGridFilter(dtStart, dtEnd);
}
if (strVal == "monthly")
{
    dtStart = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Date;
    dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
    FillGridFilter(dtStart, dtEnd);
}
if (strVal == "yearly")
{
    dtStart = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Date;
    dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
    FillGridFilter(dtStart, dtEnd);
}
if (strVal == "custom")
{
    lbldtStart.Visible = true;
    txtdtStart.Visible = true;
    lbldtEnd.Visible = true;
    txtdtEnd.Visible = true;
 }
 FillGridFilter(dtStart, dtEnd);
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: which part...because im also very confused as i get this error only when i select the custom option in dropdown, everything else is working fine

Comment: slectedindexchanged code behind event code

Comment: i think you are not initializing the dtEnd when you select the custom from dropdown check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code have some king of ambiguity. The function `FillGridFilter(dtStart, dtEnd);` it must be outside of the condition. In your code you have this function included in condition as well as outside of the condition. Means your function calls two times. Try this and make sure your date variables have values in them.

```
if (strVal == "today")
{
    //dtStart = Convert.ToInt32(ddlFilter.SelectedValue)
    dtStart = DateTime.Today;
    dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
}
if (strVal == "weekly")
{

    dtStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).Date;
    dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
}
if (strVal == "byweekly")
{
    dtStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15).Date;
    dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
}
if (strVal == "monthly")
{
    dtStart = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Date;
    dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
}
if (strVal == "yearly")
{
    dtStart = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Date;
    dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
}
if (strVal == "custom")
{
    dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
    lbldtStart.Visible = true;
    txtdtStart.Visible = true;
    lbldtEnd.Visible = true;
    txtdtEnd.Visible = true;
}

// Check either Datetime have value or its null.
if (dtEnd.HasValue)
{
    FillGridFilter(dtStart, dtEnd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your nullable DateTime `dtEnd` is not initialised for sure when you select the `custom` from the `DropDownList`

Replace this block:

```
if (strVal == "custom")
{
     lbldtStart.Visible = true;
     txtdtStart.Visible = true;
     lbldtEnd.Visible = true;
     txtdtEnd.Visible = true;
}
```

with this:

```
if (strVal == "custom")
{
     dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
     lbldtStart.Visible = true;
     txtdtStart.Visible = true;
     lbldtEnd.Visible = true;
     txtdtEnd.Visible = true;
}
```